# Demonstrate a nondenumerable set of consistent extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$ that are pairwise inconsistent.

Tags: meta-math, metalogic

> Given that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there are $2^n$ consistent, axiomatizable extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$ that are pairwise inconsistent, show that there is a nondenumerable set of such consistent extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$ that are pairwise inconsistent.

non-denumerable means an infinite set which cannot be put in one-to-one correspondence with the set of natural numbers.

Do I use the fact that the set of all sets of positive integers $P^*$ is not enumerable? I need a hint on this.

Comment: You need to use some property of the set of consistent axiomatizable extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$, because the statement doesn't hold true replacing 'pairwise inconsistent extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$' with arbitrary structures — for instance, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are $2^n$ finite bitstrings any two of which differ in at least one place, but this doesn't imply that the set of finite bitstrings is non-denumerable. Presumably you need to show that the limit/infinite union of a chain of extensions is itself a consistent axiomatizable extension.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's tweak the problem a bit. Note that if $T_1,T_2$ are individually consistent but mutually inconsistent and $S_1\supseteq T_1,S_2\supseteq T_2$ are complete and individually consistent, then $S_1\not=S_2$. This means that we can rewrite our initial result as "$\mathsf{Q}$ has infinitely many complete consistent extensions," and rewrite our goal as "$\mathsf{Q}$ has uncountably many complete consistent extensions." This isn't essential, but thinking about complete theories is in my opinion a bit easier than thinking about incomplete ones.

---

Next, let's rule out a plausible attempt. A natural thing to hope at this point is that there's a very general result here - namely, that *every* theory with infinitely many consistent complete extensions has uncountably many consistent complete extensions. However, **this is false**. Consider for example the empty language. There are countably infinitely many consistent complete theories in this language (so the empty theory in the empty language is a counterexample to the hope above):

- For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the deductive closure $A_n$ of the one-sentence theory$$\{\exists x_1,...,x_n[(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}x_i\not=x_j)\wedge\forall y(\bigvee_{1\le i\le n}y=x_i)]\}$$ is complete, and clearly $A_n\not=A_m$ if $m\not=n$.
- The only remaining complete consistent theory is the deductive closure of the following infinite set of axioms: $$\{\forall x_1,...,x_n\exists y(\bigwedge_{1\le i\le n}x_i\not=y):n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$

*(Verifying the above is a good exercise.)* So **we need to use something particular to $\mathsf{Q}$, here**.

---

OK, now finally let's get to the answer to the problem.

The key fact about $\mathsf{Q}$ we'll use is ... Godel's first incompleteness theorem! There are various forms of the first incompleteness theorem; the one we'll want is the following:

> $(*)\quad$ There is no finite set of sentences $F$ such that $\mathsf{Q}\cup F$ is consistent and complete.

*(You should check that this does in fact follow from whichever version of the incompleteness theorem you're familiar with.)*

Fix some enumeration $(\varphi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the sentences in the language of $\mathsf{Q}$. We can build a binary tree $\mathbb{T}\subseteq 2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ of "ways to extend $\mathsf{Q}$" as follows: $\mathbb{T}$ is the set of all finite binary sequences $\sigma$ such that the theory $$X_\sigma:=\mathsf{Q}\cup\{\varphi_i: i<\vert\sigma\vert, \sigma(i)=1\}\cup\{\neg\varphi_i: i<\vert\sigma\vert, \sigma(i)=0\}$$ is consistent. This is in fact a tree (that is, it is closed downwards) since a subtheory of a consistent theory is again consistent. Infinite paths through $\mathbb{T}$ correspond exactly to complete consistent extensions of $\mathsf{Q}$, so we just need to **count the paths**.

Now the consistency of $\mathsf{Q}$ means that $\mathbb{T}$ has no "dead end" nodes - if $\sigma\in \mathbb{T}$ then there is some $\tau\succ\sigma$ with $\tau\in\mathbb{T}$. However, the incompleteness fact $(*)$ above lets us do even better: it implies that $\mathbb{T}$ **has no *non-splitting* nodes**. That is, if $\sigma\in\mathbb{T}$ then there are **incompatible** extensions $\tau_1,\tau_2\succ\sigma$ with $\tau_1,\tau_2\in\mathbb{T}$. Our goal then follows from the following purely combinatorial fact, which is a good exercise:

> Every infinite tree $\mathbb{A}$ of binary strings with no non-splitting nodes has $2^{\aleph_0}$-many infinite paths.

*HINT: think about how the splitting criterion lets us embed the full binary tree $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ into $\mathbb{A}$, and how that in turn yields an embedding of the set of all infinite binary sequences into the set of paths through $\mathbb{A}$.*

What if we didn't have $(*)$? Well, consider the obstacle pointed out in the previous section: the empty theory in the empty language. The corresponding tree $\mathbb{E}$ for this theory is still infinite and still has no dead ends; however, it has lots of non-splitting nodes. In fact, there is exactly one complete theory in the empty language whose corresponding path through $\mathbb{E}$ does not go through a non-splitting node; can you figure out which it is? *(HINT: you should have in mind a picture like $\{0\}\cup\{{1\over n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.)*

---

As a coda, note that we can think of the above argument as essentially **topological** in nature, as follows. Every consistent *theory* $T$ has a corresponding nonempty *space* $Comp(T)$ whose points are complete consistent extensions of $T$. Finite axiomatizability modulo a theory corresponds to *isolatedness* in this space, so $(*)$ says that $Comp(T)$ has no isolated points. While nonempty spaces without isolated points could still only have countably many points (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology), no such space can be compact - and by the compactness theorem, $Comp(T)$ is always compact. We won't actually use the language of topology - instead we'll just talk about **paths through trees** - but the topological "flavor" is absolutely worth pointing out and will become crucial in more advanced situations.